# make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:267: arch/x86/kernel/paravirt.o] Error 255

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, boot, compiling, make

I'm trying to compile linux kernel 5.7.0rc1. But while compiling I'm facing the following errors.

I'm using this config file. Link: [.config](https://syzkaller.appspot.com/text?tag=KernelConfig&x=bc498783097e9019)

```
arch/x86/kernel/paravirt.o: warning: objtool: missing symbol for section .entry.text
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:267: arch/x86/kernel/paravirt.o] Error 255
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'arch/x86/kernel/paravirt.o'
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:488: arch/x86/kernel] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1723: arch/x86] Error 2
```

Comment: Well, it is about 3 years old that kernel, so possibly you are using a more recent compiler rather than an older one.